# Reversing a for loop... want to print numbers in reverse

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

How would I change this loop to print prime number in reverse... starting from the biggest one first

```
int main(){

    bool prime;
    for( int i=3; i<=10000; i++){
        prime = true;
        for(int n=2; n<=i-1; n++){
            if( i%n == 0){
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if(prime){
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Be aware that going in reverse precludes writing the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which would make this much faster.

Comment: No it doesn't - he could find them in order and print them in reverse.  The number of primes less than 10000 can easily be put into a stack.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "going." It would turn the Sieve into a 2-pass algorithm but wouldn't affect the storage requirement.

Comment: If you can write "for (int i=3; i<=10000; i++)" why you can't write reverse loop? As for me this question looks like "I need just an answer to give it to other person".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reverse the for loop as follows:

```
for( int i=10000; i>=3; i--) {
```

That being said - you can also simplify this.  You only need to check until you reach the square root of the number.  Also make sure that, when you find that a number isn't prime, you break out immediately:

```
int main() {

    bool prime;
    for( int i=10000; i>=3; i--) {
        prime = true;
        int max = sqrt(i)+1; // Don't check beyond this...
        for(int n=2; n<=max; n++)
        {
            if( i%n == 0){
                prime = false;
                break; // This prevents you from continually checking!
            }
        }
        if(prime){
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the direction of the outer for-loop.

```
int main()
{
    bool prime;
    for( int i=10000; i>=3; --i)
    {
        prime = true;
        for(int n=2; n<=i-1; n++)
        {
            if( i%n == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if(prime)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```